# Query using date in grails

Tags: datetime, grails

I am trying to run a query in grails and one of the fields i want to filter from is a datetime type in mysql. I tried doing this:

```
def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
def timeNow = formatter.format(new Date())
foundUsers = User.executeQuery("from User u where u.username LIKE '%"+params.searchStr+"%' and u.enabled =1 and u.expiration_date>"+timeNow,[max:20])
```

but this is giving me an error: unexpected token !
I cannot change the domain User and the database because they are old and contain live data.
So how do i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I belie  unexpected token is because of '>' after  u.expiration_date
2. Your code is not save for sql injection.
3. Your cod should be something like this

   def foundUsers=  User.findByUsernameLikeAndEnabledAndExpiration_date('%params.searchStr%',1,timeNow)

Read more about Dynamic Finders

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying

Comment: i also have to check likeness for middlename, lastname and firstname, how can i do that ? can it support so much 'likes' ?

Comment: yes you can Have
User.findByUsernameLikeAndMiddlenameLikeAndLastnameLike('%1%','%2%','%3%')

Comment: I did this
foundUsers = User.findByUsernameLikeOrFirstnameLikeOrMiddlenameLikeOrLastnameLikeAndEnabledAndExpirationDate('%params.searchStr%','%params.searchStr%','%params.searchStr%','%params.searchStr%',1,new Date())
and got error, No property found for name

Comment: I did
foundUsers = User.findAll("from User u where (u.username like ? or u.firstname like ? or u.middlename like ? or u.lastname like ?) and u.enabled = ? and u.expirationDate> ?",[searchStr,searchStr,searchStr,searchStr,true,new Date()],[max:10])
and it worked !! Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    foundUsers = User.executeQuery("from User u where u.username LIKE ? and u.enabled = 1 and u.expiration_date > ?",['%params.searchStr%', timeNow],[max:20])
```